# Getting empty value from stored procedure (sybase)

Tags: c#, sybase

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc1]
(
    @tbl1   varchar(30),
    @var2   varchar(7000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)


    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tbl1 + '(column) VALUES (''' + @var2 + ''')'

        EXEC (@sql)

        RETURN CONVERT(int, NEXT_IDENTITY(@tbl1))
    END
END
```

C# Method:

```
//create connection
using (AseConnection cn = new AseConnection(connectionString)) {
    AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand();

    AseParameter[] paras = new AseParameter[]{
        new AseParameter("@tbl1", AseDbType.VarChar, 30), 
        new AseParameter("@var1", AseDbType.VarChar, 7000),
        new AseParameter("@RetValue",AseDbType.Integer) };
    // Add all the parameters to command object
    foreach(AseParameter p in  paras) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    }

    //finally, execute the command.
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However, the third parameter is always empty. If I execute procedure directly in Sybase client, it gives me correct value.
Does anyone have good suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you show us the code for adding parameters to the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the third parameter as

```
AseParameter retParam = new AseParameter("@RetValue",AseDbType.Integer);
retParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Also, select the identity with

```
RETURN @@identity
```